# How can I make pg_search faster?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, pg-search

I'm trying to implement pg_search in my rails application. I've got it working but searches are very slow, over 20 seconds. I have over 7 million records in my `addresses` table. Are there ways I can make it faster?

#### app/models/address.rb

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord
  include PgSearch::Model
  pg_search_scope :search_for, against: %i[address_line_1 address_line_2], using: %i[tsearch trigram]
```

### UPDATE

I've added this index but it still seems to be just as slow

```
class IndexAddressesOnAddressLine1 < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  # An index can be created concurrently only outside of a transaction.
  disable_ddl_transaction!

  def up
    execute <<~SQL
CREATE INDEX pg_search_addresses_on_fields ON addresses USING gin(coalesce(address_line_1, address_line_2, ''::text) gin_trgm_ops)
SQL
  end

  def down
    execute <<~SQL
DELETE INDEX pg_search_addresses_on_fields
    SQL
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you considered adding trigram indices to the table? https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2016/03/18/fast-search-using-postgresql-trigram-indexes/

Comment: @max I'm already doing trigram and tsearch. Should I make it exclusively trigram?

Comment: Do I need to manually create an index or does pg_search handle that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Have you profiling the search feature?
- Is this 20 seconds the time it takes to query the database or include rendering the results in the application?

By default, `pg_search` uses a threshold of 0.3 for trigram searches. Higher numbers match more strictly and thus return fewer results. Lower numbers match more permissively, letting in more results.

```rb
pg_search_scope :search_for, 
  against: %i[address_line_1 address_line_2], 
  using: {
    tsearch: { dictionary: 'english' },
    trigram: { threshold: 0.5 } # increase the threshold
  }
```

I'm not sure but maybe you need to reindex your model:

```rb
rake pg_search:multisearch:rebuild[Address]
```

Comment: That rake task doesn't work for me `zsh: no matches found: pg_search:multisearch:rebuild[Address`. Maybe because I'm not using multisearch ?

Comment: How about increase your `threshold` any improvement?

Comment: `rails -T | grep pg_search` to check if your pg search rake task is available?

Comment: Threshold doesn't help. The task is there `rails pg_search:multisearch:rebuild[model,schema] `

Comment: Because you're using zsh you should escape the square bracket with `rake pg_search:multisearch:rebuild\[Address\]`

Comment: `PgSearch::Multisearch::ModelNotMultisearchable: Address is not multisearchable.`

Comment: Yes because you're using `search scope` instead `multisearch`.